# libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, unix, boost, codeblocks

Пытаюсь использовать `message_queue`. Собственно код ничего не делает, кроме вызова конструктора. 
Часть `build log`:

> /usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/main.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «pthread_condattr_setpshared@@GLIBC_2.2.5»
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main()
{ 
    message_queue(open_or_create,"message_queue" ,100 ,100);
}
```

Что происходит?

Comment: `boost` тут ни при чём, компилятор не может найти библиотеку `pthread`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .../libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096911/4827341) советуют добавить опцию

```
-lpthread
```

к опциям компилятора.

---

для того, чтобы скомпилировать ваш пример, мне пришлось добавить первой строкой:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
```

и передать компилятору опции `-lrt -lpthread`. тогда программа test из файла test.cpp компилируется удачно:

```
$ CPPFLAGS="-lrt -lpthread" make test
g++  -lrt -lpthread   test.cpp   -o test
```

описанная же вами ошибка легко воспроизводится при удалении опции `-lpthread`:

```
$ CPPFLAGS="-lrt" make test
g++  -lrt   test.cpp   -o test
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8fR82D.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_condattr_setpshared@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: Уже было добавлено, никак не влияет на ошибку(   -lprotobuf -lboost_thread /home/usr/boost_1_60_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_thread.a -lboost_system -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/main.o: неопределённая ссылка на символ «shm_open@@GLIBC_2.2.5»
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @JtheFoxx, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо